# How to set CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES to nothing

Tags: cmake

I have run into an issue when writing find scripts. For some reason, automatic appending of suffixes did not work: only library files with `.dylib` extension were found, however files with `.a` extension or no extension at all were not.

Practical experimentation lead me to setting CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES to an empty value and restoring the value afterwards. However, this has following effect:

1. When cmake is run for the first time, generation fails with "CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may not be built correctly. Missing variable is CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES".
2. When I run cmake second time the same way, generation succeeds.

My guess is, things that were found are saved in cache, and the script for finding them is not run the second time.

My question is, how can I work around that issue and ensure that both my framework (that does not have suffixes) is found and cmake does not stop generation?

I am generating on MacOS, for Xcode.

Comment: You may try to set value of `CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES` variable to `;` (single semicolon). Technically this means a list of two empty values, but it probably would pass the consistency check like `if(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES)`.

Comment: Please add that as an answer. I would like to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is an "official" way for assign a list of a single empty extension, but you may assign a list of **two empty extensions**:

```
set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ";")
```

Unlike to empty value, this assignment would pass possible sanity checks like `if(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES)`, which probably exists in CMake code as it reports about "Error required internal CMake variable not set".